# AlertDialog.Builder.setSingleChoiceItems results in a multiple choice list

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I've created an `AlertDialog` with the `AlertDialog.Builder` using `setSingleChoiceItems` to set the `ListAdapter` to a custom class that derives from `CursorAdapter`:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
builder.setTitle("Title")
       .setSingleChoiceItems(mAdapter, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
         {
           // Do nothing.
         }})
       .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
         {
           Log.d(TAG, "Ok clicked.");
         }})
       .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
         {
           Log.d(TAG, "Cancel clicked.");
         }});
```

In spite of using `setSingleChoiceItems()`, my resulting dialog contains a list with check boxes, and multiple items can be checked. I would expect to see a list with radio buttons instead.

How can I get the dialog to allow only a single item to be selected, and show that selection with a radio button?

**Update**

If I call `setSingleChoiceItems` passing a `String[]` as the list item source instead of the adapter, I get the desired result:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
builder.setTitle("Title")
       .setSingleChoiceItems(new String[] {"one","two","three"}, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
           {
             // Do nothing.
           }});
```

So it appears the adapter causes the problem. I'm still unsure why.

Comment: And yet you don't think the type of `mAdapter`, and its definition in case its a custom type, its important for your question for a problem you have with `mAdapter` but not with anything else?

Comment: It's very important. I can see this is the cause now. Thank you. The adapter is binding to a custom layout which uses check boxes. I guess I can't re-use that code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As K-ballo hinted, the problem was with the custom adapter. It was using a custom layout with checkboxes. I replaced the custom adapter with `SimpleCursorAdapter`, and it works as expected:

```
mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
                                   android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice,
                                   null,
                                   new String[] { "title" },
                                   new int[] { android.R.id.text1 },
                                   0);
```